# jScrollPane error, is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use jScrollPane and always get a Javascript error "jScrollPane is not a function". My Header looks like this

```
... 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ruda" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
```

script.js contains this line of code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(function(){ $('.scrollbar').jScrollPane(); });
});
```

My div looks like this:

```
<div class="scrollbar"><p>...</p></div>
```

And has the following styles:

```
.scrollbar {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    max-height: 550px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Whatever I tried, I keep getting this error and have absolutely no idea, how to get jScrollpane to function properly. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try $(document).ready instead of window.load?

Comment: That was my first try. Didn't work either.

Comment: found any solution to this problem? Am currently facing the same thing